# How to know which Patches to Install?

Tags: magento-1.9, security, patches, ce-1.9.1.1

Just downloaded the latest Magento Community Edition v1.9.1.1 and the first thing that popped up when I logged into the admin was that there were important security patches. I installed SUPEE-5994 as instructed because it was released after v1.9.1.1.

Is it safe to assume that the earlier patches are already incorporated with the latest release? If not, is there a way to identify which patches need to be applied on a local development server with no public URL?

I'm confused because several patches are marked as being for version 1.9.x.

Comment: did you installed SUPEE 1533 and 5344??

Answer (score 5):

Just read the changelog:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/ce1.9_release-notes.html

Ok not at the moment for the current version, hopefully they fix it soon. [But @benmarks confirmed, that in magento 1.9.1.1 is only the patch SUPEE-5344](https://twitter.com/benmarks/status/594288251533332483)

What I know: Magento is doing silent updates, so change the release data, without changing the version number, which is really bad if you ask me. **I would assume, that the [newest patch SUPEE-5994 is not part of it](https://www.magentocommerce.com/products/downloads/magento/)**. But you can just try, by applying it, than `patch` tells you whether it is already applied (or whether it seems like it.

Comment: Yes. magento 1.9.1.1 included that patch.no need to use  patch for this version..vote +1

Comment: Updated my answer to make sure you see the important part :-) So called shoplift patch is in, but not the newest!

Comment: which patch i have to install for 1.9.0 version.....

Comment: Check the download page. Every patch which is available for 1.9 and is not applied yet

Answer (score 0):

Please visit this URL and Scan your Magento shop for known security vulnerabilities.
https://www.magereport.com