# install security patches for magento 1.9.0 version

Tags: security, ce-1.9.0.0

We need to install all security patches that required for community edition [ 1.9.0 ]

In this link https://www.magentocommerce.com/download

I found that the following security patches are necessary:

SUPEE-6482, SUPEE-6237 ,SUPEE-5994 , SUPEE-5344,SUPEE-4829, SUPEE-1533 , SUPEE-4291/4334

which security do we need?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to know which Patches to Install?](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/69403/how-to-know-which-patches-to-install)

Comment: @Prateek but i am using 1.9.0 version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you have in your question should answer your question.

Just go through that list and install them one by one after that you can check

```
app/etc/applied.patches.list
```

If the mentioned patches are applied or not.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the following file :

*app/etc/applied.patches.list*

It will show you all the patches you have already applied. If the latest Magento patches are not in the list, you should install them or upgrade to the latest version of Magento which will include all previous security update patches.

Comment: i want to know which and all needs to be installed , right i did't installed any security patches.....

Comment: then the list you link to is enough. Just check the list and install the ones you need and that shoudl do it

Comment: Install them all on your test system, if all is ok, install them all on your live system.

Comment: okay @paj  i will try this.....